# Problem to blink for anther value fetched from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, dom-events

I have problem to blink textbox which values fetched from mysql and just one of them blink, but I want to blink all of them. My PHP code is below:

```
 $runquery=mysql_query($qouery,$conn);
 $runquery2=mysql_query($updatepic,$conn);
    while($rows2=mysql_fetch_array($runquery)){
        $coursename3=$rows2['course'];
        echo '<div style="float:right;margin-right:10px">';
 echo "<a class='startexam' id='paymentBlink' href='pay.php?sendnamecourse=$coursename3'>Pay:</a>";
echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$rows2['course'];
echo '</div>';
}
```

and my Javascript code is below:

```
var blink=document.getElementById('paymentBlink');
for(var i=0;i<blink.lenght;i++){
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

setInterval(function() {
    
    blink[i].style.display = (blink[i].style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
    }, 1000);

 }, false);
 }
```

Comment: You have just found out that an `id` is supposed to be *unique*.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that `mysql_` is deprecated (which means you should change all your server-side code using either `MySQLi` or `PDO`).

Change your **PHP** code to create unique id's as in the following example.

```
$runquery=mysql_query($qouery,$conn);
$runquery2=mysql_query($updatepic,$conn);
$i = 0;
while($rows2=mysql_fetch_array($runquery)){
    $coursename3=$rows2['course'];
    echo '<div style="float:right;margin-right:10px">';
    echo "<a class='startexam' id='paymentBlink".$i."' href='pay.php?sendnamecourse=$coursename3'>Pay:</a>";
    echo "&nbsp&nbsp".$rows2['course'];
    echo '</div>';
    $i++;
}
```

**Don't use `Javascript` for blink effect use `CSS` instead.**

Check the example snippet below, using `CSS` animation and `nth-of-type` to add a custom delay on the index of the element.

```css
[id^="paymentBlink"] {
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
[id^="paymentBlink"]:nth-of-type(2n) {
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

[id^="paymentBlink"]:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div id="paymentBlink1">div 1</div>
<div id="paymentBlink2">div 2</div>
<div id="paymentBlink3">div 3</div>
```